# PDO Update first binded param replaced by second

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a problem with a PDO Update sql, here is my query :

```
        App::get('database')->update(
            "UPDATE users SET log_token = :token WHERE id= :id", 
            array(":token" => $token, ":id" => intval($id))
        );
```

And here is my update function:

```
public function update($query, $params = []) {
    if(empty($query)) throw new \Exception('PDO Statement is empty');
    $sql = $this->pdo->prepare($query);
    if(!empty($params)) {
        foreach ($params as $param => $value) {
            $sql->bindParam($param, $value);
        }
    }
    $sql->execute();
}
```

The query runs and it returns true, but my problem is that the generated token (string 128 chars) is not updated in the database, but instead the ID is placed in the log_token column.

What could be the problem ? What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Because `bindParam` does not do what you expect. Open a manual and find the difference between `bindParam` and `bindValue`.

Comment: @u_mulder Oh my god. You're right. Such a dummy mistake. Thank you !

Comment: @CrisTany You can also pass the `$params` variable as a parameter to the `execute` method. Like: `$sql->execute($params);`. Take a look at this example: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php#example-1055

Comment: @RolandStarke Indeed. I think it's a better way because I no longer require a loop. Thanks.